# How to know Realm object's creation thread

Tags: android, persistence, realm

Is there any way or pattern to know/check at which thread a realm object was created? i.e. any way to know in advance if accessing realm object from current thread will throw "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created."?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not, but in general you shouldn't send RealmObjects to methods that work on other threads. Instead send the primary key and refetch or use the `realm.copyFromRealm()` method. The first is much preferable though.

You can read more about the threading model here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#threading